# ultra stamina mode in Sony Xperia Z3+

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, sony-xperia-z3

Can not turn off ultra stamina mode in my z3+ 
no application could be started 
can not access the phone from the computer 
help please

Answer (score 0):

*Ultra STAMINA mode* extends battery lifetime significantly. You can use this mode when you know you won't be able to charge your device for a long time. Only a few basic functions, such as Phone and Messaging, are available

To deactivate Ultra STAMINA mode

- Drag down the status bar to open the Notification panel.
- Tap Deactivate Ultra STAMINA mode